# How to print date and time from db if record is Null?

Tags: php, html, sql-server, database

In my db i have 2 columns with format time and date. But value is null.
When im trying print results i have error:
Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, null given in 
 my script is:

```
echo "<td>" .date_format( $row['return_time'], 'H:i:s') . "<hr>";"</td>";
  echo "<td>" .date_format( $row['return_date'], 'd/m/Y') . "<hr>";"</td>";
```

I know becouse Null in db but how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<td>".(empty($row['return_date']) ? 'no date available' : date_format( $row['return_date'], 'd/m/Y')). "<hr>";"</td>";
```

Comment: You should avoid using empty. Equiualent is using just if (!$row['return_date']) construction.